# Error when trying to open cloned project in xcode: "Could not open file"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I want to create an iOS build for my cordova app. For this i must use Xcode. I cloned the repository and tried to open it using `File > open > path` but I always get the following error:

[image: Xcode Error]

The project does not have any `.xcodeproj` or other xcode-related files in it because it was not developped in Xcode.

What I've tried already:

- I also tried opening xcode from the terminal inside the project-directory but that resultet in the same error.
- Restarted the Mac and Xcode.
- Logged out of my Apple- and GitHub accounts in Xcode and logged in again.
- Deleted all of the DerivedData files and iOS Device Logs

I'd be very glad if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/cli/index.html, there are steps how to create a project for iOS.

Here is a snapshot:

- Add Platforms

  - `cordova platform add ios`
  - `cordova platform ls`
- Build the App

  - `cordova build ios`

That should create an Xcode project.

Comment: And If I then use `File > open > path` what path to which file/folder do I have to specify?